# Plotly in R, multiple lines, group by variable

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm learning how to use plotly.

I have data from several Big Oil companies, with values per year, and I would like to see one individual line for each company over the same period. The idea is to see if the companies are diverging over this period.

I've tried various group_by solutions, but I can't figure it out. I have also looked up the suggested questions here on SO.

I'm using R.

Reproducible example:

```
data <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sveisa/r/master/tot_summary.csv"
data <- read_csv(url(data))

fig <- plot_ly(data, 
               x = ~year,
               y = ~all_terms_ratio,
               name = 'all_terms', 
               type = 'scatter', 
               mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig
```

Comment: You will likely need to add each group using `add_trace`. Take a look at Plotly's "Plotting Markers and Lines" example. This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes I did that for other variables, but I don't know how to group by company names ('ticker' in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the `color` or `group` argument. This plots each group separately. Note that you would have to change the shown group name prior within the data.

```
source <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sveisa/r/master/tot_summary.csv"
data <- read_csv(url(source)) %>% 
  # not necessary, just for clarity reasons
  dplyr::arrange(ticker, year)

plot_ly(data, x = ~year, 
        y = ~all_terms_ratio, 
        # groups and assigns different colors in one step
        color = ~ticker,
        # name = 'all_terms', 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig
```